# EOS time lapse problem: stops taking shots

Tags: timelapse, eos-utility

I'm having a problem shooting time lapse on my canon 60D with EOS Utility on mac.

The timer stops shooting after 1-5 shots.

In "Timer Shooting Settings", If i enter 5000 shots in the "Shots (minimum 2)" box, it takes only 5 shots, then stops.

Entering 4000 shots gives 4 shots, 3000 gives 3, etc.

What's going on here?

[image: Timer shooting settings]

Comment: That's strange. Could you maybe add a screenshot of the timer shooting settings?

Comment: Update: if I enter 999 shots, it works fine, but I'd like more.

Comment: [Here](https://www.flickr.com/groups/40d/discuss/72157624901225274/) a similar problem. Could you see if setting the preference `Linked software` to `none`solves the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your comment noting that it works if you enter 999, I suspect that you are suffering the effects of poor user interface design. Sounds like the camera has an actual limit of 999, and UI doesn't inform you of that or limit your input. It's an open Question whether the software's back end is truncating out-of-date "5000" to "5", or whether that's happening in the communication with your camera, but either way, seems like that is the issue. I think k your best bet may be to look for more sophisticated software.